# Is $f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac1k\sin\frac x{2^k}$ bounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, summation

> $$f(x)=\sum_{k\in\mathbb N}\frac1k\sin\frac x{2^k}$$Is this function bounded?

So obviously this converges because $|\frac1k\sin\frac x{2^k}|<|\frac x{2^k}|$ and $\sum\frac x{2^k}$ converges by the integral test.

Now I need to show that there exists a $N$ for all $y\in\text{range}\,f$ such that $|y|<N$.

So I think:

Let $a_k=\frac1k$ and $b_k=\sin\frac x{2^k}$. From the Schwarz inequality we get $|\sum a_kb_k|\leq\sqrt{\sum|a_k|^2\sum|b_k|^2}$. Since $a_k>0$ for all $k$ we have $a_k=|a_k|$ and thus $|a_k|^2=\frac1{k^2}$. $\sum\frac1{k^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$ from the Reimann-Zeta. Now all we have left to prove is that $\sum|b_k|^2$ is bounded as well.

Comment: Hint. We have $|\sin \theta| \leq |\theta|$ for *any* real $\theta$.

Comment: @sos440 Oops, I missed that. Let me see if that gets me anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. I though your question was something about pointwise, but now I see your question is the *boundedness* of $f$ itself. I will keep thinking about it.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian It's a special case, I think. From Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis, theorem 1.37 part e.

Comment: The statement is true but it isn't Cauchy-Schwarz. Acutally nevermind on that hint though.  I didn't think it through fully.

Comment: This sinusoidal sum is something I've never dealt with before. No idea what to do.

Comment: So far I was only able to prove that $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(1+\left|\log x\right|)$.

Comment: @sos440 Sorry, I just came out of single variable calculus and I don't recognize that math.

Comment: It means that there exists a constant $C$ such that $\left| f(x) \right| \leq C (1 + \left| \log x \right|)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function is unbounded. In fact, take $x_m = \frac{2^{3m}}7 2\pi$; then the sequence $f(x_m)$ tends to infinity. To see this, note that
$$
\sin\Big( \frac n72\pi \Big) \approx \begin{cases}
0.781831, &\text{if }n\equiv1\pmod 7, \\
0.974928, &\text{if }n\equiv2\pmod 7, \\
-0.433884, &\text{if }n\equiv4\pmod 7.
\end{cases}
$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
f(x_m) &= \sum_{j=1}^m \bigg( \frac1{3j-2}\sin\Big(\frac{2^{3m-(3j-2)}}7 2\pi\Big) + \frac1{3j-1}\sin\Big(\frac{2^{3m-(3j-1)}}7 2\pi\Big) + \frac1{3j}\sin\Big(\frac{2^{3m-3j}}7 2\pi\Big) \bigg) \\
&\qquad{}+ \sum_{k=3m+1}^\infty \frac1k\sin\Big( \frac\pi{7\cdot 2^{k-3m-1}} \Big) \\
&\approx \sum_{j=1}^m \bigg( \frac{0.974928}{3j-2} - \frac{0.433884}{3j-1} + \frac{0.781831}{3j} \bigg) + \sum_{k=3m+1}^\infty \frac1k\sin\Big( \frac\pi{7\cdot 2^{k-3m-1}} \Big) \\
&> \sum_{j=1}^m \frac{0.44}j + \sum_{k=3m+1}^\infty 0 > 0.44 \ln m.
\end{align*}

Comment: Good! Plus +1 upvote. So it turned out that the bound $f(x) = \mathcal{O}(1+\left| \log x \right|)$ was in some sense optimal.

Comment: This just means you can't use the Schwarz inequality, right?  Or does this prove that the overall function is unbounded?

Comment: sos440 - indeed! ND - the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is valid, but the $\sin^2$ sum is itself unbounded as a function of $x$ (indeed on the same subsequence $x_m$).